# While using string function in C++ getting terminated by using substr() function

Tags: c++, string, function, substr

** Im currently want to use whole string that it should contain space between them so Im using getline() function but after code getline() my code is getting terminated,I dont know why this happening**

````
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        while (n--)
        {
            string m;
            getline(cin, m);
            string s1 = m.substr(1);
            string s2 = m.substr(6);
            string s3 = m.substr(9);
            string s4 = m.substr(15);
            cout << s1 << s2 << s3 << s4 << endl;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Before you assign the strings, print the length of `m`and then look at your code again.

Comment: Is your input at least 16 characters long? Otherwise, exceptions will be thrown.

Comment: @molbdnilo the input is "12:00 AM 11:23 PM"

Comment: If you verify, for instance with `cout << '|' << m << '|' << endl;`, that you actually read what you believe that you read, you will most likely notice that the string is empty, and that's because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction).

Comment: @molbdnilo then what I can do

Comment: For starters, read the question and answers I linked to.

Comment: @molbdnilo I got the answer getline(cin.ignore(),m)  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
char input[100];
cin.getline(input, sizeof(input));
string str = input;
cout << str.substr(1) << " " << str.substr(6) << " " << str.substr(9) << " " << 
str.substr(15) << "\n";
```